# What is creating the infinite loop in my ajax code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This should be easy, I just cant catch what's the problem for almost an hour so maybe I'm missing something.

I want to create a responsive contact form without a "thank you" page, so I am using ajax.

I wrote all the code, 
this is my responce I get on my console:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

that keeps running infinitely.

This is my form:

```
    <div id="contactform" style="position: relative; top: 180px; left: 50px;">
        <table width="600px" class="contactform" >

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">  Full Name: <br/> </td>
                <td colspan="2"> <input type="text" id="fullname" />   </td>    
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">  Phone Number: </td>
                <td colspan="2"> <input type="text" id="telephone"/> </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">  Email Adress: </td>
                <td colspan="2"> <input type="text" id="email"/> </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"> Subject: </td>
                <td colspan="2"> <input type="text" id="subject" /> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"> Content: </td>
                <td colspan="2"> <textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="text"> </textarea> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">  </td>
                <td colspan="2"> <input type="button" class="link" value="Send" id="sendBtn" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

this is my ajax code part from the .js file:

```
$('#sendBtn').click(function(){
    //get info 
    console.log("dude!");
    var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
    var telephone = $("#telephone").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    var text = $("#text").val();
    //send info to php 
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
    //      $("#spin").html(spiner);
        },
        url: 'http://www.example.com/MYtest/contact.php', 
        type: "POST", 
        data: ({ "fullname": fullname, "telephone": telephone, "email": email, "subject": subject, "text": text }), 
        success: function (results){
    //      $("#spin").hide(spiner);
            console.log(email);

            //hide table 
            $('#contactform').hide('slow', function() {
                // Use arguments.callee so we don't need a named function
                $('#contactform').hide( "slow", arguments.callee );
              });
            //show textboxes
            $('#aboutSuccess').show("slow");
        }
    }); 


});
```

and this is my content.php :

```
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email_to = "meEmail@example.com";
        $email_subject = "You have a new email from example.com";

        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
        $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; 
        $email = $_POST['email'];       
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];   
        $text = $_POST['text'];     

        $message = "Full Name: ". $fullname ."\n Telephone: ". $telephone ."\n Email: ". $email ."\n Subject: ". $subject ."\n \n Message: \n". $text;

        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message);
    }
```

Comment: I would guess it is the `$('#contactform').hide( "slow", arguments.callee )` which might call `arguments.callee` immediately when the element is already hidden. Why do you want to use `arguments.callee` at all?

Comment: Your recursive hide table callback is the problem.  I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `arguments.callee` inside the function. That's what causing the loop.

```
$('#contactform').hide('slow', function() {
    // Use arguments.callee so we don't need a named function
    $('#contactform').hide( "slow", arguments.callee );
});
```

I don't get what you are trying to do with this code, maybe it's leftovers. Try replacing it with:

```
 $('#contactform').hide('slow');
```